# Spring Integration transactionSynchronizationFactory without a poller

Tags: transactions, synchronization, spring-integration

According to the following code, it seems that transactionSynchronizationFactory is only available for a poller. Nevertheless a poller introduce a new thread. Then the question is: how to stay in the first transaction, but using a transactionSynchronizationFactory? The flow should be like that (using a direct channel instead of a queue):

Gateway -> JPA updating gateway -> direct channel (to stay in the same thread) -> file outbound adapter

```
    @MessagingGateway
    public interface School {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "school.input")
        void add(StudentDomain student);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow school() {
        return f -> f
                .handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(this.entityManagerFactory)
                        .entityClass(StudentDomain.class)
                        .persistMode(PersistMode.PERSIST), e -> e.transactional(true))
                .handle("conditionalService", "databaseTransaction")
                .channel(fileWritingChannel());
    }

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    ConditionalService conditionalService(){
        return new ConditionalService();
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel fileWritingChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();              // Queue for the poller (transactionSynchronizationFactory is only for pallable resources ?)
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileWritingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(fileWritingChannel())
                .handle("conditionalService", "fileTransaction", e -> e.poller(Pollers
                        .fixedDelay(1000)
                        .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
                        .transactional(pseudoTransactionManager())))
                .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("file_name", "student.json"))
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File( "." + File.separator + "output2")).autoCreateDirectory(true))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    PseudoTransactionManager pseudoTransactionManager(){
        PseudoTransactionManager pseudoTransactionManager = new PseudoTransactionManager();
        return pseudoTransactionManager;
    }

    public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
        TransacSynchro syncProcessor = new TransacSynchro();
        return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
    }

    class TransacSynchro implements TransactionSynchronizationProcessor {
        @Override
        public void processBeforeCommit(IntegrationResourceHolder holder) {
            //System.out.println(holder.getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void processAfterCommit(IntegrationResourceHolder holder) {
            Message message = holder.getMessage();
            if(message != null){
                System.out.println("processAfterCommit: " + holder.getMessage());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void processAfterRollback(IntegrationResourceHolder holder) {
            Message message = holder.getMessage();
            if(message != null){
                System.out.println("processAfterRollback: " + holder.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Otherwise a transactionSynchronizationFactory can be used with an ImapIdleChannelAdapter:

```
@Bean
    public ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter(ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver) {
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(imapMailReceiver);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(receiveChannel());
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory());

        return imapIdleChannelAdapter;
    }
```

But what about with an output file adapter? 
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear - it makes no sense to add the Tx sync factory to an outbound endpoint since the transaction won't commit or rollback until the thread returns to the transaction interceptor, In any case you are calling the gateway on a thread so you will implicitly know whether the transaction committed or rolled back and can take appropriate action in the caller to the gateway. If you want the whole flow to run in a transaction (not just the JPA) you need to start the transaction - either in the calling code or by adding `@Transactional` to your messaging gateway.

Comment: You also need a real JPA transaction manager - not a pseudo one.

Answer (score 0):

The `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` was really introduced for those components which are not initiate from end-user code. The poller and `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` are samples of those components which do their job in their own threads and you don't have any access to the TX finish from them.

A regular `.handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(this.entityManagerFactory)` is more end-user event driven component, so you can `try...catch` their transaction finish to perform some particular logic.

An `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` may help you with that alongside with the mentioned `e.transactional(true)`. So, you wrap a call into some advice which will react to the normal finish and to an exception thrown downstream.

See more info in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gary and Artem for your quick responses.
So, on the main program I can use @Transactional:

```
@Transactional
public void manyStudentsInTheSameTransaction(){
        StudentDomain morgane = new StudentDomain("C", 20);     
        school.add(morgane); // no exception => added to the transaction
        StudentDomain loic = new StudentDomain("D", 50);            
        school.add(loic); // exception in the same transaction => C and D are rollback in the database
}
```

and try...catch:

```
try{
        conditionalService.manyStudentsInTheSameTransaction();
} catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Catched ecxception: " + e);
}
```

It works in the database: both students are rolledback since an exception occurs for the second one. Good!

The workflow looks like that:

Gateway -> JPA updating gateway -> direct channel -> file outbound adapter

But what I am trying to do now is to manage the files the same way transactions do for the database. Ok, you suggest to deal with files in the catch clause. Nevertheless **I don't want to deal with it in the catch clause** because, since database transactions play their roles behind the scene, I expected to do the same with files.

Then I tried your solution Artems with an ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice:

```
    @Value("${orcha.rollback-transaction-directory}")
    String rollbackTransactionDirectory;

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface School {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "school.input")
        @Transactional
        void add(StudentDomain student);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow school() {
        return f -> f
                .handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(this.entityManagerFactory)
                        .entityClass(StudentDomain.class)
                        .persistMode(PersistMode.PERSIST), e -> e.transactional(true))
                .handle("conditionalService", "databaseTransaction")
                .channel(fileWritingChannel());
    }

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    ConditionalService conditionalService(){
        return new ConditionalService();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel fileWritingChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileWritingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(fileWritingChannel())
                .handle("conditionalService", "fileTransaction", c -> c.transactional(true).advice(expressionAdvice()))
                .enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(h -> h.put("file_name", "payload.getFirstName()")))
                .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File( "." + File.separator + "output2")).autoCreateDirectory(true))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public Advice expressionAdvice() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        //advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
        //advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
        advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload");
        advice.setTrapException(false);
        return advice;
    }

    /*@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow success() {
        return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
    }*/

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow failure() {
        return f -> f.<ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException, StudentDomain>transform(m -> (StudentDomain) m.getEvaluationResult())
                .enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(h -> h.put("file_name", "payload.getFirstName()")))
                .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File( "." + File.separator + rollbackTransactionDirectory))
                        .autoCreateDirectory(true));
    }
```

Now the workflow looks like this:

Gateway -> JPA updating gateway -> direct channel (to stay in the same thread) -> file outbound adapter <=> ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice

As expected, the two students of the main program are rolledback in the database (thanks to the @Transactional), but **only one of the students is finally considered as rolledback for the file outbound adapter**:

```
    @Transactional
    public void manyStudentsInTheSameTransaction(){

        StudentDomain morgane = new StudentDomain("C", 20);     

// no exception => added to the database transaction and (unfortunatly) considered as ok for the outbound file adapter

        school.add(morgane);

        StudentDomain loic = new StudentDomain("D", 50);    

// exception in the same transaction => C and D are rollback in the database (good), D is considered as non ok for the outbound file adapter (good), but C not (bad)

        school.add(loic);
    }
```

So, to conclude and going back to the subject of the original post, I though transactionSynchronizationFactory was a solution to deal with file transactions like database transactions, but as you said Artem:

> The TransactionSynchronizationFactory was really introduced for those components which are not initiate from end-user code

But the question remais the same: how to use transactionSynchronizationFactory, or equivalent solutions, for components initiated from end-user code.

Sorry for this long question. Thank you very much.